# When linear map is bounded and bijective then $X$ is reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking for the proof of : 
If $T$ is bounded ,bijective linear map from $X$ to $Y$ where $X$ and $Y$  are Banach spaces, then $X$ is reflexive if and only if $Y$ is reflexive . 
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Taking the second dual gives $T^{ **}:X^{ **}\rightarrow Y^{ **}=Y$.

Comment: @paulgarrett  can you tell me what is $T^{**}$ ?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : I edited .

Comment: Ok, so what do you know about reflexivity?

Comment: @David Giraudo : the fact that canonical embedding is isomorph from Banach space to its dual. But how do i go about dealing with the linear transformation. I haven't yet learnt many theorems about reflexivity . But i guessed that it doesn't require more results .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To amplify slightly my comment: given $T:X\rightarrow Y$, the adjoint $T^*:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ is characterized by $(T^*\mu)(x)=\mu(Tx)$ for $x\in X$ and $\mu\in Y^*$. Doing this one more time gives $T^{**}:X^{**}\rightarrow Y^{**}$...